# Deploying .NET Core 1.1 App to Docker - Could not resolve CoreCLR path

Tags: .net, docker, deployment, .net-core, coreclr

We are trying to deploy our .NET Core app to docker.

*Assume that our project base located on `/source.`*

When we run `dotnet restore` `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` in `/source`, everything is ok.

However when we trigger `dotnet publish -c Release -o publish`, go inside `publish` folder and attempt `dotnet OurAppName.dll` (running the app directly from dll), this error is throwed:

```
Could not resolve CoreCLR path. For more details, enable tracing by setting COREHOST_TRACE environment variable to 1
```

Summary: `dotnet run` works correctly in `source` folder, `dotnet OurAppName.dll` crashes in `publish` folder when trying to run dotnet core app in a docker container. What can be the problem?

We already tried `latest` and `1.1-sdk-projectjson` tags in our `DockerFile`.

Comment: may help https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/988

Comment: thanks but does not work

Comment: Can you show what your project looks like?  Also, can you list what the OurAppName.runtimeconfig.json says in the publish folder?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? Same issue here.

Comment: I have tried dotnet 1.0 instead of 1.1 and it worked however it is not a solution. Today I am going to try from scratch and update here.